# merging a dictionary with svm model to multiclass text classification mission

Tags: dictionary, classification, svm, text-classification

I have a collection of articles from news sites
and i want to classify them into the appropriate categories.
for example i have some categories like sport,politcs,art,business,etc...
and some articles and want to classify each one to the appropriate category.

i think two combine a dictionary that consists of categories and relatedwords for for each category
and svm model.
in the dictionary i will save the relatedwords in its root, also i will convert the text before classify to root words (by nltk.stemming library)

first i will classify by the dictionary (i will search the occurance of the words in the text)
and i case the dictionary didn't succeed. then i will use svm to classify (the trainig of svm will be a set of news articles with their labels)

my questions :1) Does the merging of the two methods sound fine or is the dictionary unnecessary?
2)i know svm is for binary classification but in some website i read its recommended also for multiclass text classification. is svm really good for classify text to more than two catgories ?
3)if svm isn't good for this mission,What other model is recommended for the mission ?

thanks